# How both definitions of a lie group are equivalent

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I can't proof that these definitions of lie groups are equivalent.
Can anyone prove it directly?.

1. A Lie group is a set which carries the algebraic structure
   of a group and the differentiable structure of a smooth manifold such that the
   mapping
   $$ G\times G \rightarrow G \hspace{1cm} (a,b) \mapsto ab^{-1}$$ 
   is smooth
2. A Lie group is a set which carries the algebraic structure
   of a group and the differentiable structure of a smooth manifold such that the
   mappings
   $$ G\times G \rightarrow G \hspace{1cm} (a,b) \mapsto ab$$ 
   and
   $$ G \rightarrow G \hspace{1cm} g \mapsto g^{-1}$$ 
   are smooth

Comment: Presumably the restriction $1\times G\to G$ (i.e. inversion) must be smooth and hence the composition of inversion with $ab^{-1}$ (i.e. multiplication $ab$) is also smooth.

Comment: In fact, it suffices to require smoothness of the multiplication, smoothness of the inversion then follows from the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 3):

1 implies 2.

Since $m:(a,b)\rightarrow ab^{-1}$ is smooth, and $i(a)=(e,a)$ is smooth, $i_v(a)=m\circ i(a)=a^{-1}$ is smooth.

$ f:(a,b)\rightarrow (a,i_v(b))=(a,b^{-1})$ is smooth and $m\circ f(a,b)=ab$ is smooth.

2. implies $a$,

let $g(a,b)=ab, m=g\circ (Id_G,i_v)$.

Comment: Excellent proof. Thanks